# On Scroll function working in wrong direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am calling a function on window scroll using this code :

```
$(function()
{
   $(window).scroll(function()
   {
        if($(document).height()==$(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height())
        {       
                    alert("At Bottom");
                    LoadMore();

        }
   });
});
```

Now the problem is, this function is working in opposite direction.

When I scroll down, it does nothing, but when I scroll top it works, why is this so ? I have implemented it in another project, and it was working fine, but now its working in opposite direction. Can anyone help me ? Any other better code or solution ?

Comment: This code should work fine. Do you have a live link?

Comment: http://test.fretbay.com/fr/sent.php?idsess=SzssevgQoEMcUww3HBpZOiW1RM9MHZ&type=sent

Comment: Why are you loading jquery twice?

Comment: Its not even working with one

Comment: Seems to be working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/rN7pL/

Comment: On your site, set `body`  height using CSS: `body{height:100%;}`, this will fix your issue. And please, load only one jquery version

Answer (score 0):

When you're at the bottom, the scroll top will equal the body's scroll height - its offset height.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var body = $("body");

    if (body[0].scrollHeight - body.height == body.scrollTop()) {
        //place code here: you've reached the bottom
    }
});
```

Comment: @CodeHunter I edited my answer to make it a little better. Does that work for you? I'm on my phone so it would be a pain to make a Fiddle, plus I don't even have an account yet. :P

Comment: @A.Wolff are you sure? His code dosen't seem right, yet I haven't been able to experiment since I'm on my phone. I just gave the method I've always used, and I've never had a problem, no matter what element I use this code on.

Comment: @CodeHunter did you try my answer? :)